# Change wallpaper by current time

Tags: scripts, customization, desktop-background

While customizing my Ubuntu I thought to have two wallpapers, one for the day/afternoon and one for evening/night.

Is it possible to change the wallpaper basing myself to the current time? If so, how can I?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Change wallpapers according day & night as simple as it gets

Assuming the night begins somewhere *after* 12:00 am and ends *after* midnight 24:00, usage of the script below is as simple as it gets:

- Run it in the background with the command:

  ```
    python3 <script> <begin_of_evening> <end_of_night>
  ```

for example:

```
    python3 /path/to/wallpaper_shift.py 19:00 6:00
```

- During the day shift, set the wallpaper as you like. The script remembers your choice on the next day shift.
- Likewise, during night shift, set your preferred wallpaper for the night. Again, the script remembers.

That's all. Now the wallpaper will switch according the moments of the day you set, running the script.

#### If the script is stopped

The script remembers the set wallpapers in a hidden file: `~/.wallset`. WHen the script is (re-) started, it first tries to read the set wallpapers from the file. if it does not exist, it creates a new file, using the currently set wallpaper for both day- and night shift, until you change either one (or both).

#### Processor load zero

When the script is started, it calculates:

- the current time of the day
- the time span of night- and day shift
- the time span from the current time of the day until the first switch
- the current term (either day or night)

After that, between the wallpaper switches, the script only *sleeps*

*what the script does*

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import sys
import time

def write_walls(prefsfile, walls):
    # write new set of wallpapers to prefsfile
    open(prefsfile, "wt").write(("\n").join(walls))

def set_wall(wall):
    # set the wallapaper
    new = wall.replace("night:", "").replace("day:", "")
    command = "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "+\
              new
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
    
def get_currwal():
    # get the current wallpaper
    return subprocess.check_output([
        "/bin/bash", "-c",
        "gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri"
        ]).decode("utf-8").strip()

def produce_setwalls(prefsfile):
    # on startup of the script, try to read the set wallapapers
    # or take the currently set on first run
    try:
        return open(prefsfile).read().splitlines()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        currwall = get_currwal()
        newwalls = ["night:"+currwall, "day:"+currwall]
        write_walls(prefsfile, newwalls)
        return newwalls
        
def convert_tosecs(t):
    # convert time of the day (hrs/mins) to seconds
    t = [int(n) for n in t.split(":")]
    return (3600*t[0])+(60*t[1])

# --- set constants
day_period = 24*3600
prefsfile = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.wallset"
# ---

# --- define time- shifts
curr_t = convert_tosecs(time.strftime("%H:%M"))
t1 = convert_tosecs(sys.argv[1])
t2 = convert_tosecs(sys.argv[2])
# ---

# --- define start- data
if any([curr_t > t1, curr_t < t2]):
    curr_term = "night"
    first_period = 86400 - curr_t + t2
else: 
    curr_term = "day"
    first_period = t1 - curr_t
# ---

# --- define time spans
night_shift = 86400 - t1 + t2
day_shift = 86400 - night_shift
# ---

# run first term, set wallpaper according (possible) settings
set_wallpapers = produce_setwalls(prefsfile)
to_set = [wall for wall in set_wallpapers if curr_term in wall][0]
set_wall(to_set)
time.sleep(first_period)

# then start loop
while True:
    if curr_term == "day":
        new_daywall = "day:"+get_currwal()
        sleeptime = night_shift
        new_term = "night"
    elif curr_term == "night":
        new_daywall = "night:"+get_currwal()
        sleeptime = day_shift
        new_term = "day"
    
    toremove = [item for item in set_wallpapers if curr_term+":" in item][0]
    # replace possibly changed wallpaper in the prefsfile and the currently
    # used set of wallpapers
    set_wallpapers.remove(toremove)
    set_wallpapers.append(new_daywall)
    write_walls(prefsfile, set_wallpapers)
    # switch daytime <> night, set the wallpaper accordingly
    curr_term = new_term
    set_wall([item for item in set_wallpapers if new_term+":" in item][0])
    # sleep again...
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

###How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `wallpaper_shift.py`
2. Test- run it from a terminal by the command (example):

   ```
    python3 /path/to/wallpaper_shift.py 19:00 6:00
   ```

where the time format should be `20:00`
3. In any of the two terms, simply set the wallpaper as you like, the script remembers and re- applies it on the next "day" or "night".
4. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

```
    /bin/bash -c "sleep 20 && python3 /path/to/wallpaper_shift.py 19:00 6:00"
```

#### Notes

1. The script works correctly if the evening *starts* between 12:00 a.m. and ends *after* midnight. That seems however obvious.
2. The script rounds the time *on minutes*, meaning that the accuracy is also somewhere between 0-60 seconds.
3. .wallset file will show:

`night:'file:///home/user/path/to/file/123.jpg' day:'file:///home/user/path/to/file/456.jpg'`

4. If you prefer to use cron to execute the script in background, open your terminal and execute this command: `crontab -e`

then, add this line into the crontab:

```
 @reboot /home/user/path/to/wallpaper_shift.py 19:00 6:00
```

and save the crontab setting (i.e. `CTRL-x` if you are using nano).
This will execute the wallpaper_shift.py script to run in background every time you reboot/boot your system.

Comment: Very nice and interesting answer.  Thanks. Hope it will be useful to somebody else too :).

Comment: Very nice!  I used this script and it works like a charm.  I also implement a crontab job for this script to be run in background everytime my system reboot/boot.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [Automatic Desktop Wallpaper Changer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/wallch/). It's pretty simple to use.

Comment: It sounds like it works just for Ubuntu with GNOME DE.

Comment: @alexj123 so it didn't work for you? Did you try to use it?

Comment: I solved myself. Thanks for the answer anyway :).

Answer (score 2):

I recently wanted to do the same and found a way to achieve it with shell script. (*in Ubuntu 20.04 that uses GNOME*)

Perform the following steps:

1. Create the script that updates the wallpaper based on time of day, *Filename: change_wallpaper.sh:*

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   HOUR=$(date +%H)
   case "$HOUR" in
   04|05|06|07)
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /path/to/sunrise-image
   ;;
   08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17)
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /path/to/morning-image
   ;;
   18|19)
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /path/to/evening-image
   ;;
   *)
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri /path/to/sunset-image
   ;;
   esac
   ```
2. Make *change_wallpaper.sh* file executable.

   ```sh
   sudo chmod +x change_wallpaper.sh
   ```
3. Add this shell script to the list of startup scripts,

   **Activities -> Startup Application Preferences -> Add**
4. Set up a CRON job to call this shell script at specific times of the day

   *Filename: change_wallpaper.cron*

   ```
   0 4,8,18,20 * * * /path/to/.change_wallpaper.sh
   ```

   Run Command:

   ```sh
   $ crontab /path/to/change_wallpaper.cron
   ```

Inspired by [this post](https://jihedamine.github.io/automatically-changing-wallpaper).

**Update:**

The call to **change_wallpaper.sh** from cronjob may not work. It didn't work for me. On searching online I found that using the `gsettings` command from cronjob, required an extra step as it was modifying sensitive data.

Steps to make the cronjob working:

1. Run the following command:

   ```sh
   echo $(cat /proc/$(pgrep -n "gnome-session" -u "$USER")/environ | grep -z "^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=")
   ```

   Output will be like :
   **DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus**
2. Update the file *change_wallpaper.cron*, with output from the above command :

   ```
   0 4,8,18,20 * * * DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1001/bus /path/to/.change_wallpaper.sh
   ```
3. Run command :

   ```sh
   $ crontab /path/to/change_wallpaper.cron
   ```

Reason why the extra step is required is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250297/464275).

The extra step code is inpired from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1059023).

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you want to do it yourself but why reinvent the wheel

Simply run:

sudo apt-get install wallch

and configure as needed.

Comment: If I am notmistaking, this answer was already given...

Comment: I tried wallch, its about 100MB of code including its dependencies. From what I saw it had a feature for setting up wallpapers based on time intervals, but not with respect to time of day.